# SQL Server Profiler - Error Details

Tags: sql-server, profiler

I enabled the whole error-section but it only says smth like:

```
Exception: Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.
```

It's good to know, but what's about the details? I wanna know what particular query caused this and all the other verbose information. Is there a way to attain this?

I checked SQL Statement Starting/Completed, SP Starting/Completed etc. What more should I enable to make it show more details I need?

Comment: `SQL:Batch Completed` should show you the statement along with any parameters if I remember correctly?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the ability to, when you begin your profile session, select the TSQL_REPLAY template.  This will provide all the details you need.

Comment: Any other option? This solution implies to rerun all traced commands, isn't so?

Comment: Interesting template. One of the rows returned was called "Attention", no idea what that is.